# manual update kivy screen when a user function is doing heavy computation

Tags: python, kivy

I want to visualize a computing process in kivy. The problem is that kivy freezes when the python function runs. Any ideas how to manage that problem.

It is like a progress bar. The computation is running and the user should see that his PC did not hang up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your computationally intensive stuff in one or more threads or separate sub-processes and have them periodically post some updates to the GUI to say how they are doing, (and the results at the end of course).

Comment: mixing python threads (import threading) and the kivy threading mechanism (Clock.schedule_once) is not a good idea. This can lead to blocking.
I am looking for an "easy" solution which does not involves a setup up of an multiprocess/multitread enviroment.

Comment: Kivy clock scheduling isn't threading, except *maybe* in a vague conceptual way with no technical implications. Anyway, you can probably use it for what you want, if you can divide your process into small chunks and run them one by one with Clock.schedule_interval or Clock.schedule_once (with each one calling the next).

Comment: @StefJa Python threads work just fine with Kivy Clock - I use them extensively for communicating with hardware. Kivy also uses threads internally.

Comment: Threading/Multiprocessing is the way that just about every GUI I have come across stays responsive while doing intensive calculations whether programmed in Python, C, C++, even Assembler (they call is time-slicing or preemption there).

Comment: the solution of @steve-barnes is good. Kivy has no public function to trigger the GUI and input computations. For that you have to create and run a threading.Thread object. Do not call "join" to wait for the thread function because it will cause the kivy thread to block.